# I want to start bounty for a question

Tags: discussion

I asked the following question [Does removing a GUI from a server make it less vulnerable?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/192336/does-removing-a-gui-from-a-server-make-it-less-vulnerable)

But I don't get enough reputation as I expected, once I start a bounty and I did get a reputation as I paid, I was maybe I did not select the appropriate kind of bounty, would please share your professional opinion that this question worth to start a bounty to get more "reputation"?

Comment: I'm going to close this question, as based on your comments below it doesn't really make any sense. I'd suggest going back to the [about] pages and really reading them to see how Stack Exchange works - it appears you are trying to use it in some other way.

Comment: @RoryAlsopI am not using it in any other way, it was an honest question.

Comment: honest, but misguided, I think

Answer (score 4):

You post a bounty in order to get attention to the question so that you can get *answers*, not *reputation*. That question is your highest voted question on StackExchange and the community has up-voted one Answer 114 times. The community thinks that you have your answer.

Comment: As you mention I have the answers I expected but I need more attention to the question, how can I get more attention, is it possible to have more or got enough attention due to the subject?

Comment: *Why* do you want more attention?

Comment: I think the question has more potential.

Comment: Potential to do *what*? What is the end state?

Comment: To have more view to get more reputation, i dont know the end state, some times can not see the end and i dont have the answer for every question.

Comment: The end state, in this case, is to have higher reputation. Ok, so you want to game the bounty system to get more rep. This question is not what Meta is for.

Comment: If you want higher rep, take a look at the questions that have high rep. Look at their subjects and how they are crafted. In particular, look at how *specific* they are. You are having trouble getting rep because you are trying to write answers to get more rep. That is not going to work. You gain rep by ofering ***value** to the community, not by asking questions you think other people might want to know.

Comment: No, i want to no your professional idea that this question is worth more reputation?

Comment: There is no professional idea that any post deserves more or less reputation. It's up to the community and what they are interested in at the time. I have had answers that I thought would get 1-2 rep, and they got 100-200 because the question made it to the Hot Network Questions list. I wrote others that I thought would get a ton of rep, but got nothing. You cannot predict or expect any certain amount of rep for anything.

Comment: If you want to build high rep, then you need to provide consistent, long-term value over time. And mostly, you will see that the highest rep members answer more questions than they ask. That's where the value to the community is. Questions mostly provide value to yourself.